# Observer Magento - Order Cancel

Tags: magento

I wonder what the correct event that I observe when a sale is canceled.

I'm trying to "sales_order_item_cancel" but I do not know if that's correct. Besides how can I get the ID of the sale?

I'm trying this way:

> `$order = $observer->GetEvent()->GetOrder()->getID();`

but not working.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should always be camel case `..->get[Xyz]()`

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
```

See 
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php    1139    order_cancel_after
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php   512 sales_order_item_cancel

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_item_cancel', array('item'=>$this));
```

Since `sales_order_item_cancel` dispatch `item` try

```
print_r($observer->getEvent()->getItem())
```

Comment: When I try to pass the instruction:                          
`$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getID();`

I get the following error:                     
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getID() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\loja_facil\app\code\community\Novapc\CancelarPedido\Model\Observer.php`

Comment: Also should be '->getId()' (camel case), but I dont think that will work because `sales_order_item_cancel` dispatch  `item` so try print_r($observer->getEvent()->getItem()->getOrder()->getId()); die();

Comment: Now it worked perfectly, with all necessary information.

Thank you

Comment: Which code did you use $observer->getEvent()->getItem()->getOrder()->getId()?

Comment: $order = $observer->getEvent()->getItem()->getData();
  $order_id = $order['order_id'];

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better to use `sales_order_payment_cancel` if you want to observe the whole order and not just single items.
You can access the order by `$order = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder();`

Cheers
Simon